# How to correctly run this simulation?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simulation but for some reason or other I get an "list index out of range" error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong precisly.

```
import numpy as np
import math

roomPrice = 280
dayAvailable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dayDemand = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [1,2,3]]
customers = np.random.poisson(lam=250, size=1000)
deny = 0
customersDenied = []
bookings = []
customersHelped = 0
capacityFull = 0

def priceAccept(p): 
    value = 1/(1+math.exp(0.025*p-7.5))
    return value

for c in customers:
    capacity = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
    probability = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,], 
                                   size = c, 
                                   p = [0.15,0.05,0.1,
                                        0.05,0.1,0.2,
                                        0.1,0.1,0.05,0.1])
    for prob in probability:
        for i in dayDemand[prob]:
            if capacity[i] == 0:
                capacityFull += 1
                deny += 1
        if capacityFull == 0:
            priceAcceptCustomer = np.random.choice([1,0], size = 1, p=[priceAccept(roomPrice),1-priceAccept(roomPrice)])
            if priceAcceptCustomer == 1:
                for d in dayDemand[prob]:
                    if capacity[d-1] > 0:
                        capacity[d-1] -= 1
                        customersHelped += 1
    bookings.append(customersHelped)
    customersDenied.append(deny)
```

It keeps returning the following at `if capacity[i] == 0:`

> IndexError: list index out of range

How can I fix this simulation to run correctly?

Comment: capacity has five elements, so the valid indexes are 0 through 4.  Index 5 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexation begin with `0`. So, the maximum value of `i` for capacity is `4`. Thus, `IndexError: list index out of range` will be raised when `i` will be equal to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the size of `dayDemand` is 10, `capacity` is 5:

```py
print(len(dayDemand))   # 10
print(len(capacity))    # 5
```

If *i > 4* in the loop below, you will get this error because `capacity` is not the *6th* or `capacity[5]` element of the array

```py
for i in dayDemand[prob]:
    if capacity[i] == 0:
        capacityFull += 1
```

Comment: Ah ok. So if I would change dayDemand to start at 0 and go through to 4 (basically shifting it all down 1) then it should work?